# Añadir tiempo a resultado impreso en terminal (cronjob)

Tags: bash

Tengo un cronjob configurado de la siguiente forma:

```
0 * * * * php ~/ruta/archivo.php >> ~/log.txt
```

El `archivo.php` tras realizar una sincronización de datos, devuelve dos posibles respuestas:

- La base de datos se actualizó correctamente
- La base de datos está actualizada

Eso lo guarda perfectamente en el `log.txt` pero cuando quiero añadirle al cron la fecha del comando:

```
date +'%Y-%m-%d %T' // 2016-01-12 21:59:06
```

Según yo, me quedaría algo como lo siguiente:

```
0 * * * * php ~/ruta/archivo.php $(date +'%Y-%m-%d %T') >> ~/log.txt
```

Pero al ver el log, no me guarda dato alguno del comando `date`, me muestra las impresiones como lo siguiente:

```
La base de datos está actualizada
La base de datos está actualizada
La base de datos está actualizada
La base de datos se actualizó correctamente
La base de datos está actualizada
La base de datos está actualizada
...
```

En cambio si ejecuto lo siguiente si funciona como espero:

```
echo 'Soy un texto: ' $(date +'%Y-%m-%d %T') >> ~/log.txt
```

El texto en el log queda:

```
...
Soy un texto: 2016-01-12 21:59:06
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes combinar los resultados de multiples comandos con `{ }`. Entonces, en tu crontab:

```
0 * * * * { php ~/ruta/archivo.php; date +'%Y-%m-%d %T'; } >> ~/log.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

El comando php esta ejecutando el archivo y luego la segunda parte `$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %T')` lo interpreta como argumento, no como parte de la ejecución.

Intenta

```
php -r "include('file.php'); echo Date('formato');" >> log.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

En esta forma :

```
0 * * * * php ~/ruta/archivo.php $(date +'%Y-%m-%d %T') >> ~/log.txt
```

`date` se ejecuta y su salida se utiliza como segundo parámetro del comando php.

Lo que quieres lo puedes (casi) lograr con :

```
0 * * * * php ~/ruta/archivo.php >> ~/log.txt ; date +'%Y-%m-%d %T' >> ~/log.txt
```

Aquí los comandos php y date se ejecutan uno detrás de otro y la salida de ambos va a ~/log.txt
Pero esto tiene un problema, que puede que sea o no significativo para ti. cron envia un e-mail cuando un trabajo cron finaliza en error (exist status distinto de 0).
Con la línea anterior si php devuelve un status distinto de 0 esto va a quedar oculto por la ejecución de date.

Si el recibir e-mail en caso de error de php es importante para ti, puedes crear un script, por ejemplo en /usr/local/bin/php_con_fecha.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
php ~/ruta/archivo.php >> ~/log.txt
res=$?
date +'%Y-%m-%d %T' >> ~/log.txt
exit $res
```

El cual invocarías con :

```
0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php_con_fecha.sh
```

El script guarda el resultado de php y la fecha en el log como quieres. Y su exit status será el mismo que el del comando php.

Answer (score 1):

Hay sutiles diferencias entre la ejecución de un comando directamente escribiendo desde el shell y cuando los ejecutas desde una línea del crontab. Una de estas diferencias, es que los signos `%` deben de escaparse con `\`

El ejemplo que presentas:

```
0 * * * * php ~/ruta/archivo.php $(date +'%Y-%m-%d %T') >> ~/log.txt
```

Quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
0 * * * * php ~/ruta/archivo.php $(date +'\%Y-\%m-\%d \%T') >> ~/log.txt
```

Entonces. el archivo log.txt según el contexto quedaría con este contenido:

```
 La base de datos se actualizó correctamente 2016-01-12 21:59:06
```